# Floating point that make the calculation inaccurate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I didn't set the datetype of variable in ruby .I use the default datatype so that make the final calculation inaccurate .How to solve？

```
   scores = params[:scores].split("\r\n").map { |n| n.to_f }  # array of scores (at most 2 decimal points,e.g 2.32 ,23,65.76.....)

#new array 
 sd=Array.new(scores.length,0)


    sd[0]= (scores[0]-average)**2  # calculation <<== sd[i] become 234.08999999999992
470.8900000000001
13.69000000000002
0.6399999999999955
 86.48999999999995

sd[1]= (scores[1]-average)**2
sd[2]= (scores[2]-average)**2
sd[3]= (scores[3]-average)**2
sd[4]= (scores[4]-average)**2

 sd_sum=sd[0]+sd[1]+sd[2]+sd[3]+sd[4]

sd_sum=sd_sum**2  ...
gg=sd_sum/5       # further calculation 
ans=Math.sqrt(gg) # final answer for standard deviation
```

As the final answer has proccessed many steps of calculation ,it become inaccurate .

Comment: _"I didn't set the datatype"_ – you might not be aware of it, but you did: `n.to_f` explicitly converts `n` to a float.

Comment: @Stefan  floating point referring to unlimited decimal points ? -->inaccurate calculation -->avoid to use in calculation ?

Comment: Floating point numbers are approximations, see my answer below.

Comment: I think your code might be wrong: you shouldn't need to square `sd_sum`, and it is unclear where `average` comes from. Outside of a few edge cases (such as when all values are the same, or you have extremely large values), floating point error should generally be fairly minimal.

Comment: @Simon Byrne I simplify the code. No need worry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve the accuracy of calculations use [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead of [Float](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Float.html):

```
 scores = params[:scores].split("\r\n").map { |n| BigDecimal(n) }
```

> `BigDecimal` provides support for very large or very accurate
>   floating point numbers.
>
> Decimal arithmetic is also useful for general calculation, because it
>   provides the correct answers people expect–whereas normal binary
>   floating point arithmetic often introduces subtle errors because of
>   the conversion between base 10 and base 2.

Comment: can u explain the use of bigdecimal ?

Comment: @Vito: see [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: @Andrey Deineko floating point referring to unlimited decimal points ? -->inaccurate calculation -->avoid to use in calculation ?

Comment: @Vito correct, always use decimals for accurate calculations.

Comment: bigdecimal= decimal ?

Comment: @Vito roughly speaking - yes. [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) is just a *Ruby class*, representing the [Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal).

Comment: @Vito but even BigDecimal has its limits. For example, it cannot represent ⅓ exactly, nor √2.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's (or IEEE) floating point numbers are *approximations* of real numbers. An in-depth explanation can be found here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Unfortunately, floating point numbers are shown as if they were accurate, which leads to a lot of confusion. It would be much clearer, if the *exact* values were shown, which are:

```
2.32  #=> 2.319999999999999840127884453977458178997039794921875
23.0  #=> 23.0
65.76 #=> 65.7600000000000051159076974727213382720947265625
```

From the three numbers above, only `23.0` can be represented exactly, the other two are approximations of the actual numbers (one slightly below, the other slightly above). I think it's obvious that you can't expect accurate result from these.

Comment: The point of that article is that floating point numbers _are_ real numbers (well, except for Inf and NaN): it's the operations with them (arithmetic, conversion to/from decimal) that are approximate.

Comment: @SimonByrne I should have been more precise, IEEE floating point numbers are approximations due to the finite number of bits they have to be stored in.